# Set Input value in quotes if there is two or more words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-select

Actually i want the input value of [React Async Select](https://react-select.com/async) to be in Quotes if the searching value exceeds one or more words , i.e with spaces.

```
const handleSearchText = (value) => {
    let split = value.split(' ')
    console.log('splie',split);
    if(split.length > 1){
        let searchText = ' " ' +  value + ' " '
        console.log('searachtext',searchText);
        setSearchText(searchText)
    }
    setSearchText(value)
}
```

This is the code for on search input change.Im using split and checking if the length crosses more than 1 and setting the word with quotes

```
<AsyncSelect
                                    inputValue={searchText}
                                    onInputChange={handleSearchText}
                                    className='search-modal-select'
                                    components={{
                                        IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                                    }}
                                    styles={customStyles}
                                    placeholder='Search Terms'
                                    loadOptions={getData}
                                    loadingMessage={() => 'Getting Terms...'}
                                    value={searchTerm}
                                    onChange={(option) => handleSelectChange(option)}
                                    isClearable={searchTerm?.value ? true : false}
                                    noOptionsMessage={() => 'Type to Search Terms...'}
                                />
```

But the text is not reflect in the search.Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You're calling setSearchText with the original value regardless of whether it's got a space in it or not.

Comment: Oops, i forget to add else part

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your second `setSearchText(value)`inside else block. You also don't need to split. Also, since you are calling this function on `onInputChange`  you will unnecessarily add double quotes after every space. You need to replace the double quotes in `handleSeachText` and add them conditionally when you set the value

```js
const setSearchValue = searchText => {
    if (/\s/.test(searchText.trimStart())) {
      searchText = `"${searchText}"`
    }

    return searchText;
}

<AsyncSelect
...
onInputChange=(value => setSearchText(value.replace(/"/g, '')))
value={setSearchValue(searchText)}
...
/>
```

If you really need to change the results of the dropdown, then you should update the dropdown options not use the hacks to show double quotes like this. As, this may lead to bugs.

Comment: """""""asd "a"s"d" "a"s" its appending the quotes with it

Comment: I think we need some regex for this

Comment: No we want only the first and last quotes right, the other quotes are following up whenever i type

Comment: @Aashiq please check the updated answer, also please share codesandbox if possible to fix the actual bugs and do it in correct way

Comment: Actually i want to do this in Search text only not in options